# Rails fetch serialized model record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, orm, redis

I'm setting up a redis store where my session user_id values are stored in the cookie and the rest of the model data (first_name, last_name, username, etc...) are stored in redis. I'm very new to Redis and I'm not sure how to store the model data.

I have two questions:

1. What's the best way to store it, should I serialize it in XML, JSON or a ruby object equivalent.
2. When the stored data is fetched, how can I transform that into a working model object? That way when I do user_fetched_from_redis.username then it would work like user_fetched_from_db.username. And if there are any fields that are not fetched from the redis store then I would want activerecord to do a SELECT * FROM statement to populate all the attributes in the object. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem can be found here in another post.

[Existing Rails model without fetching it from the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638734/existing-rails-model-without-fetching-it-from-the-database)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at how [resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) handles this. Basically, they're using JSON objects instead of XML or a dumped Ruby object, and I would advocate using the same approach as it means less overhead. Rails offer very simple `.to_json` functionality for a lot of different objects, including ActiveRecord instances.

If you use JSON to serialize your object, it will expand into a normal hash when you deserialize it. It wouldn't be hard to pass this to create a custom class that could inherit the attributes and use `method_missing` to either get the attribute from the json object, or load the relevant database record. Something like this should work:

```
class CachedObject
  attr_accessor :attributes

  def initialize(json)
    self.attributes = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(json)
  end

  def method_missing(method)
    attributes[method.to_s] || Model.find_by_id(attributes['id']).send(method)
  end
end

obj = CachedObject.new('{"id":"123","foo":"some value"}')
p obj.foo # => "some value"
p obj.bar # => Executes `Model.find_by_id(123).bar`
```